# Is it possible to remotely debug precompiled (not CSX) Azure Functions?

Tags: function, azure, remote-debugging

It seems to be possible to [debug C# script (CSX) Azure Functions remotely](https://www.markheath.net/post/remote-debugging-azure-functions), is it possible to debug the precompiled C# Azure Functions remotely as well?

Comment: I guess this may be a drawback. Did you check out the issues mentioned here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1672? Also, i'm not sure but maybe this tutorial might help https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Visual-Studio-Tools-for-Azure-Functions

Comment: Thanks @OjasviBhargava the video is old and talking about debugging Azure Functions locally. However, the github thread talks about remote debugging which seem to work for some, thank you.

Comment: In the mentioned github thread are detailed instructions how to make it work, however, it still didn't work for me. If you manage to authenticate to the remote process and get 'The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document' message, make sure to select ''Managed (CoreCLR) code" in Debug -> 'Attach to Process...'

Answer (score 0):

Follow instructions https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/393 If you manage to authenticate to the remote process and get 'The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document' message, make sure to select 'Managed (CoreCLR) code' in Debug -> 'Attach to Process...' - this is a known bug which will be fixed soon.